# Detect when there is a biometric change in local_auth Flutter

Tags: flutter, fingerprint

Using loca_auth in Flutter, is it possible to detect when a fingerprint is added/deleted to the device?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, this goes [out of scope of "local_auth"](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88848), which is why you can check the change of biometrics only on your own or using third-party packages.

I found [did_change_authlocal package](https://pub.dev/packages/did_change_authlocal) - it can check the change of biometrics on Android and iOS.

Comment: did_change_authlocal library only checks the changes when apps are still in the background. That means if the app is closed/terminated, the library can't detect if the biometric is changed or not. I have tested and opened the issue on the lib.

Answer (score -1):

You can't detect if a new fingerprint is added or deleted because that would violate the App and PlayStore Rules.

Comment: But the applications of banks somehow get this information